# Regex to find all digits in sequence

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a super screwed up data sets, with no real pattern, all I need from it is to find digit sequences from 3 to 7 digits, this is what I have been trying but matches.Count always gives 0

```
Function catchNumbers(inSt As String)

Dim regex As Object, str As String
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regex
  .Pattern = "\d{3-7}"
  .Global = True '
  .IgnoreCase = True
End With

inSt = Replace(inSt, ".", "")

Set matches = regex.Execute(inSt)

Debug.Print (matches.Count())

If matches.Count() > 0 Then
    For Each StrFound In matches
        Debug.Print (TypeName(StrFound) & " : " & StrFound)
        str = str & " " & StrFound
    Next StrFound
Else
    str = ""
End If

If Left(str, 1) = " " Then
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
End If

Debug.Print (str)

catchNumbers = str

End Function
```

Example of datasets :

> 25.802; 24.052/Guaiba
>   25.802; 24.052/Guaiba
>   25.859, L. 3-Ac, Fls.5; 25.862, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 6; 25.865, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 7; 25.856, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 4
>   25.859, L. 3-Ac, Fls.5; 25.862, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 6; 25.865, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 7; 25.856, L. 3-Ac, Fls. 4

Comment: Use comma instead of hyphen: `\d{3,7}`

Comment: [This site](http://regexr.com/) is helpful to test your strings

Comment: I totally read the title as *One Regex to rule them all, One Regex to find them, One Regex to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them* ..okay maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comma instead of hyphen: `\d{3,7}`